# React-native-reanimated animation not working on ios, works in android

Tags: ios, react-native, animation, react-native-ios, react-native-reanimated

I have an animation for a bottom bar that goes under the tab text, the animation is working fine in android but not in ios. I am using react-native-reanimated.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
const MyTabBar = React.memo((props) => {


const {state, descriptors, navigation, position, setEnableSwipe, swipeEnabled, layout, theme, auth, ui} = props;
  if (state.routes[state.index].state && state.routes[state.index].state.index !== 0) {
    if (swipeEnabled === true) {
      setEnableSwipe(false)
    }
    return null;
  }
  else {
    if (swipeEnabled === false) {
      setEnableSwipe(true);
    }

    var tabWidth = (layout.width - 50)/3
    const left = Animated.interpolate(position, {
      inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
      outputRange: [(tabWidth - 50)/2 , tabWidth + (tabWidth - 50)/2, 2*tabWidth + (tabWidth - 50)/2]
    });
    const length = Animated.interpolate(position, {
      inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
      outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3, 1, 0.3],
    })
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' && ui.showing_modal ? 'white' : 'white', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
          const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
          const label =
            options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
              ? options.tabBarLabel
              : options.title !== undefined
              ? options.title
              : route.name;
  
          const isFocused = state.index === index;
  
          const onPress = () => {
            const event = navigation.emit({
              type: 'tabPress',
              target: route.key,
              canPreventDefault: true,
            });
  
            if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
              navigation.navigate(route.name);
            }
          };
  
          const onLongPress = () => {
            navigation.emit({
              type: 'tabLongPress',
              target: route.key,
            });
          };

          const inputRange = state.routes.map((_, i) => i);
          const opacity = Animated.interpolate(position, {
            inputRange,
            outputRange: inputRange.map(i => (i === index ? 1 : 0.4)),
          });

          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              accessibilityRole="button"
              accessibilityStates={isFocused ? ['selected'] : []}
              accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
              testID={options.tabBarTestID}
              onPress={onPress}
              onLongPress={onLongPress}
              style={{flex: 1}}
            >
              <Animated.Text style={{ 
                opacity, 
                fontWeight: index === state.index ? '600' : 'normal', 
                fontSize: index === state.index ? 19 : 17,
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}>
                {label}
              </Animated.Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
         {Platform.OS === 'ios' && false ? 
      <View/> :  <Animated.View 
      style={{
        backgroundColor: theme.primaryColor, 
        translateX: left, 
        scaleX: length,
        height: 4, 
        width: 50, 
        position: 'absolute', 
        bottom: 0,
        borderRadius: 10,
      }} />}
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={{minWidth: 50, maxWidth: 50}}
          onPress={() => {
            switch (state.index) {
              case 0:
                navigation.navigate('AddSchedule');
                break;
              case 1:
                navigation.navigate('AddScene');
                break;
              case 2:
                if (auth.accesstoken) {
                  navigation.navigate('NewGeoscene');
                } else {
                  ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger('notificationWarning', {
                    ignoreAndroidSystemSettings: true,
                    enableVibrateFallback: true
                  }) 
                }
                break;
              default:
                //
            }
          }}
        > 
          <Text style={{fontSize: 36, color: theme.primaryColor}}> + </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
})
```

this is my code, the line Animated.View doesn't animate in iOS so I am not rendering it there, but i want it working.

Android
[Expected behaviour (android)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I0k9.gif)

iOS:
[behaviour in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7XwA.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an observation from my own code which may or may not be applicable here. This observation is only true if both of the `transform` properties are using react-native-reanimated animation values. Your code appears to match this scenario.

In iOS only, I *must* place the `scale` property before the `translateX` property in my `transform` object. If I put the `translateX` property before the `scale` property then the `translateX` property is impeded.

I have no explanation for this, but I have tested it with `scaleX` since that's what you are using and the same is true.

So for clarity, the following works:

```
<Animated.Value
  style={[{
    transform: [{
      scale: animationValue1,
      translateX: animationValue2,
    }]
  }]}
/>
```

..while in the next, the `scale` works but the `translateX` does not:

```
<Animated.Value
  style={[{
    transform: [{
      translateX: animationValue2,
      scale: animationValue1,
    }]
  }]}
/>
```

You'll notice my syntax is a little different from yours too. As far as I'm aware you shouldn't be putting the `translateX` and `scaleX` properties in the `style` object without being wrapped in a `transform` property, as above. Perhaps reanimated's `View` works a bit differently to react native's native one.. If it's still not working after you try reordering the properties then give this some thought too.

See the documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms#transform

It's a bit confused because the API describes `transform` as a function, but the example at the top of the page shows it used as I have done above.

Comment: Thank you. When I moved the translateX into transform it fixed the problem. I didn't move scale to transform it worked anyway. And thus didn't face the problem caused by the order. I'll move the scale inside, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Does this imply to Layout animation also with reanimated 3. I am having th same issue working fine on androind but not on IOS.

```
 <Animated.View entering={FadeInDown.duration(500)} style={{position:'absolute', bottom:50, width:'100%'}}>
      <Pressable
      style={({pressed})=>[styles.btn, pressed ? {opacity:.8} : '' ]}>
        <Text style={{alignSelf:'center', color:'#ffffff', fontSize:hp('2.5%'), fontWeight:'500', textTransform:'uppercase'}}>Buy Ticket</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </Animated.View>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sir The code which I have posted on above comment is for Animated button. This is working fine on androind but the animation doesn’t work on ios.